# Difference between "same to you, too" vs "same to you"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference, word-order

I'd want to know what is the difference between `"same to you, too"` vs `"same to you"`. Like people does use just `"you, too"` as well, but is it valid to use `"same to you, too"` or that's what the correct way really is.

Comment: Well, what's the difference between "I have a dog" and "I have a dog, too"?

Comment: @Robusto First person would say "I have a dog" and second would "I have a dog, too", that's the difference. How is this relevant?

Comment: You don't see how knowing why and how to use *too* in a sentence is germane?

Comment: Basically the question is which one is valid, out of mentioned two.

Comment: The point is, *either* can be valid depending on what you mean.

Comment: I don't see how the two statements would mean different things. I think the "too" would be redundant here (but not grammatically incorrect).

Comment: @JeezLouise: No, it's not redundant. The word *too* carries some semantic freight. "Did you get a bonus this year?" and "Did you get a bonus this year, too?" mean different things. If you don't understand the difference, perhaps you and those who upvoted your comment need a little more work on adverbs. See https://www.thefreedictionary.com/too

Comment: I know what the word "too" means. But the sentence "Same to you" implies that someone has already said something that you're agreeing with, e.g. "I hope you have a great day!" "Same to you!" is a natural response to this, and is equivalent to "Same to you, too!" I believe that the *same* and *too* are redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same to you.

Same to you, too.

Both are correct. However, the former is far more usual and idiomatic than the latter as the use of the "too" is redundant in this phrase.
6
When you wish the same thing to somebody as they wish to you, you usually say "Same to you".

Answer (score 0):

The "too" is redundant and unneccessary. Without it the reciprocity is clearly implied.

Comment: That’s not the answer obviously.